# Z3py model returned EMPTY

Tags: string, z3, z3py

I converted z3 format to z3py but the model return empty string. It should give me string with equal or more than 5 letters.

```
(declare-const z String)
(assert (>= (str.len z) 5))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

```
from z3 import *
s = Solver()
a = String('a')
s.add(Length(a) >= 5)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

what's the wrong on the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axel explains why such printouts can be confusing. If you're dealing with strings that have such characters, the idiomatic way to deal with them is to use the `encode` method:

```py
from z3 import *
s = Solver()
a = String('a')
s.add(Length(a) >= 5)
print(s.check())
print(s.model()[a].as_string().encode('unicode_escape'))
```

This prints:

```
sat
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out what is going on, you could analyse the solution:

```
from z3 import *
s = Solver()
a = String('a')

s.add(Length(a) >= 5)

print(s.check())
m = s.model()

def showChar(c):
    return c if ord(c) > 20 else "[" + str(ord(c)) + "]"

for c in str(m[a]):
    print(showChar(c))
```

Resulting output:

```
sat
"
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
"
```

The string is in fact five or more characters long.